# Multiple Screen Size/Density support

Tags: android, screen

I am creating an application for Android phones and have been using an emulator to test. I have created a SurfaceView and overwritten the onDraw function to draw bitmaps on the canvas.
I also have some text that I am drawing onto this screen using the canvas.drawText function. I defined the text size as 21 using a paint.setTextSize.

The problem I am facing is that on different emulators with different resolutions and screen sizes the text can range from looking too large to too small. Is there some way to fix this using the AndroidManifest file or modifying the .xml files? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your android manifest?

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable=["true" | "false"]
                  android:smallScreens=["true" | "false"] 
                  android:normalScreens=["true" | "false"] 
                  android:largeScreens=["true" | "false"] 
                  android:xlargeScreens=["true" | "false"]
                  android:anyDensity=["true" | "false"] />
```